# How can I create a json-like variable inside a php class?

Tags: php, class

How can I create a json-like variable inside a php class?
Example:

```
<?php 
    class person {
        var $details;
        var $name;
        function set_name($new_name) {
            $this->name = $new_name; 
        }
        function get_name() {
            return $this->name; 
        }
    }
?>
```

So `$details` would be something like:

```
{ address: '', birthdate: '', email: ''}
```

Then I'd access it like:

```
var x = new person();
$x->details->email;
```

Comment: use a php associative array.

Comment: @DanielA.White: would post an example as answer, please?

Comment: There's nothing different about variables inside a class and outside.

Comment: you could make it a new class too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an associative array:

```
$details = array('address' => '123 Main St', 
                 'birthdate' => '2001-02-03', 
                 'email' => "account@domain.com"
                );
```

Then you would access it as:

```
$x->details['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `json_decode` function.

First, assign a `JSON` construct to the instance variable, something like this:

```
<?php

class Person {
    public $details;
    public $name;
    function __construct($name, $details) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->details = json_decode($details);
    }

}

?>
```

Then on, you can access the object property like this:

```
<?

$person = new person('Noman', '{ "property1": "value1" }');

echo($person->details->property1);

?>
```

You can adapt the class design to your needs but this gives you the basic idea of how to do it.